# Android Parse -- ParseQuery with List equality condition for field/column

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse, and I just want to get all the entries in my data class that have a certain List in my "blah" field/column.

```
final ParseQuery<Data> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Data.class);
query.whereEqualTo("blah", mSomeValueList);
query.setLimit(MAX_DATA_TO_SHOW);
query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
// Execute query for messages asynchronously
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Data>() {...});
```

I had hoped it would be that simple, but I get the following exception when trying to run the query: com.parse.ParseException: equality needs a value instead of [*value0*, *value1*, *...*]

How can I get my List of Data objects that have this condition?

Comment: Did you managed to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `whereEqualTo`whereEqualTo

```
public ParseQuery<T> whereEqualTo(String key,
                                  Object value)
Add a constraint to the query that requires a particular key's value to be equal to the provided value.
Parameters:
key - The key to check.
value - The value that the ParseObject must contain.
Returns:
Returns the query, so you can chain this call.,
```

there is also a `whereContainsAll`, `whereMatchesQuery`, `whereDoesNotMatchQuery`, and so on..

For **detailed** documentation refer to this [link](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereContainedIn(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection))

Hope it helps.